# I can't make a dynamic background image in vuejs, the url doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Im trying to make 6 blocks with different background images, i tried different options but none of them works,

This works:

```html
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${require('../assets/images/img/img-1.jpg')})` }"></div>
```

These two doesnt work even if 'test' is literally the right path for the img:

```html
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${require(test)})` }"></div>
```

```html
<div class="col-4 jum-block" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(test) + ')' }"></div>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
   name: "Component",
   data() {
      return {
         test: "../assets/images/img/img-1.jpg",
         cardImgPath: "../assets/images/img/",
         images: [
            { img: "img-1.jpg" },
            { img: "img-2.jpg" },
            { img: "img-3.jpg" },
            { img: "img-4.jpg" },
            { img: "img-5.jpg" },
            { img: "img-6.jpg" },
         ],
      };
   },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think require is needed inside url function, try removing require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the usage of `require()`, I'm assuming your project is a Webpack-based project (scaffolded from Vue CLI).

The `require()` argument cannot be a *fully dynamic expression* for the same [reason that `import()` calls cannot](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import):

> #### Dynamic expressions in import()
>
> It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as `import(foo)`. Because `foo` could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project.
>
> The `import()` must contain at least some information about where the module is located. Bundling can be limited to a specific directory or set of files so that when you are using a dynamic expression - every module that could potentially be requested on an `import()` call is included. For example, `` import(`./locale/${language}.json`) `` will cause every `.json` file in the `./locale` directory to be bundled into the new chunk. At run time, when the variable language has been computed, any file like `english.json` or `german.json` will be available for consumption.
>
> ```js
> // imagine we had a method to get language from cookies or other storage
> const language = detectVisitorLanguage();
> import(`./locale/${language}.json`).then((module) => {
>   // do something with the translations
> });
> ```

In your case, you could change your `require()` argument to include the image's path directory:

```html
<div v-for="image in images"
    :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${require('../assets/images/img/' + image.img)})` }" ></div>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         images: [
            { img: "img-1.jpg" },
            { img: "img-2.jpg" },
            { img: "img-3.jpg" },
            { img: "img-4.jpg" },
            { img: "img-5.jpg" },
            { img: "img-6.jpg" },
         ],
      };
   },
};
</script>
```